# ABS() vs x *-1 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function

I was wondering what the difference is between SQL Server's `ABS()` function or multiplying the value by -1 ?

Will this have a impact on my speed of my queries?

Comment: testing each scenario shows you that they are logically different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ABS()` will always returns a positive result where as multiplying by -1 will do as math laws says: it will change the symbol of the number. 
You can execute the code below to see the effects in sql server.
If you are working with finance then you would use multiply by -1, but if you are just ensuring positive values you use `ABS()`

```
DECLARE @Var INT
SET @Var = -22
SELECT ABS(@Var),@Var * -1
SET @Var = 22
SELECT ABS(@Var),@Var * -1
```